# Выпадающее меню проваливается под iframe с флешом

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, windows-7, iframe

Вообщем известная проблема с флешом, который по умолчанию показывается всегда сверху. Известно и лечение проблемы - выставление параметра wmode в opaque или transparent, и назначение z-index-ов.
Все это работает, кроме...
Кроме IE11 на Windows 7. Например, в том же IE11 на Win8 глюков нет.
А на Win7 - вот такая шляпа ((( Я тестировал на 64 битной версии. Если у кого есть 32-х битная - отпишитесь.

Comment: css `z-index` не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовали. Хотя, возможно, есть какая-то правильная последовательность их назначения (в IE уже с этим сталкивались).